# Is Windows start-job session based?

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, user-data

when I configured the start job as part windows ec2 user data

```
start-job -ScriptBlock {consul agent -data-dir C:\\consul\\logs -config-dir C:\\consul\\conf.d\\}
Start-Sleep -s 30
```

soon after the instance state becomes available, I logged into the machine and check the service is running in background or not using the following command

```
Jobs
```

the result show no jobs are running

my questions

1. is the start job session based
2. how do I make the start job work even after user data execution is completed
3. will he receive job function help with this issue

Comment: `Jobs` is not a PowerShell command. Try `Get-Job`. And what do you mean by "make the start job work even after user data execution is completed"? Jobs are not services.

Comment: how can i make the jobs to run as a service

Comment: Which part of "jobs are not services" requires more explanation? Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: i need the command consul agent -data-dir C:\\consul\\logs -config-dir C:\\consul\\conf.d\\ to be run as a service, in which the command should run 24/7 as a service do you have any prototytpe to run it as a service

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run the Consul agent as a service try creating an actual service with the [`sc`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb490995.aspx) commandline utility:

```
sc.exe create <name> 'binPath= <commandline>' start= <starttype>
```

Note that the `=` character is part of the option names, so there must be a space after but no space before it.

In your case the command would probably look somewhat like this:

```
sc.exe create ConsulAgent 'binPath= C:\consul\consul.exe agent -data-dir C:\consul\logs -config-dir C:\consul\conf.d' start= auto
```

If the commandline contains paths with spaces in them you need to put these paths in double quotes.

The service can be deleted like this:

```
sc.exe delete ConsulAgent
```